# How to populate A multi-dimensional array to multi-dimension object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I've been trying to figure for quite a while on populating my 2D array to object. I tried using `_.map()`, but it did not gave me the result I was expecting.

I have an array that is stored:

```
// My array
var myArray = [ [foo, bar, fiz], [faz, far, fee] ];

// My object
var myObject = {
    key1: {
        val1: 1,
        val2: 2,
        val3: 3
    },
    key2: {
        val1: 1,
        val2: 2,
        val3: 3
    }
}
```

And the result I am trying to achieve is:

```
var myObject = {
    key1: {
        val1: foo,
        val2: bar,
        val3: fiz
    },
    key2: {
        val1: faz,
        val2: far,
        val3: fee
    }
}
```

Here what I got so far:

```
_.map(myObj, x => {
    for (var i = 0; myArray.length; i++) {
        x.val1 = myArray[i][0];
        x.val2 = myArray[i][1];
        x.val3 = myArray[i][2];
    }
}
```

The issue I encountered with `_.map()` I want it to iterate only one time. Since the length of array and object is the same, I don't think is necessary to iterate twice. Unfortunately my array does not have a key which I can use it to distinguish, or else I would have used `Object.assign()`.

Comment: are the keys always `key1` and `val1`, or are they different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the object's original values are discarded, and the keys of the object can  be reproduced easily, you can build the object from the array using 2 [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) methods:

```js
var myArray = [ ['foo', 'bar', 'fiz'], ['faz', 'far', 'fee'] ];

var myObject = myArray.reduce(function(obj, arr, i) {
  obj['key' + (i + 1)] = arr.reduce(function(o, item, j) {
    o['val' + (j + 1)] = item;
    return o;
  }, {});
  
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Very nice example of use for reduce function.

Answer (score 0):

For a conversion, you need a double nested loop for each array. Then generate the key and build the object and content.

```js
var array = [['foo', 'bar', 'fiz'], ['faz', 'far', 'fee']],
    object = {};
    
array.forEach(function (a, i) {
    var key = 'key' + (1 + i);
    object[key] = object[key] || {};
    a.forEach(function (b, j) {
        object[key]['val' + (1 + j)] = b;
    })
});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For variable keys, you could use some arrays with the keys and take it for the outer and inner level.

```js
var array = [['foo', 'bar', 'fiz'], ['faz', 'far', 'fee']],
    topKeys = ['key1', 'key2'],
    subKeys = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
    object = {};
    
array.forEach(function (a, i) {
    object[topKeys[i]] = object[topKeys[i]] || {};
    a.forEach(function (b, j) {
        object[topKeys[i]][subKeys[j]] = b;
    })
});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```